# Existence of a self-similar symmetric subset of the unit square with non-trivial Lebesgue measure

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure, fractals

I am trying to find out whether there exists a Borel set $F\subset[0,1]^2$ that is strictly self-similar and symmetric and such that $0<\lambda(F)<1$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. We say $F$ is strictly self-similar and symmetric if it is strictly self-similar in the sense of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity) definition and if it is symmetric in both diagonals of $[0,1]^2$. An example would be if, for example, every one of the smaller squares $F\cap[0,1/2]^2$, $F\cap[0,1/2]\times[1/2,1]$, $F\cap[1/2,1]\times[0,1/2]$ and $F\cap[1/2,1]^2$ are replicas of $F$. The [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) is an example of what I'm looking for, except that it has Lebesgue measure 0.

I suspect that such a set does not actually exist. I have looked at the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension) list of fractals and at [rep-tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile#Rep-tiles_as_fractals), but there does not seem to be anything that satisfies exactly what I'm looking for. I also found [this paper](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/102044/) on an attractor of Cantor-type with positive Lebesgue measure, but I'm not sure if it is symmetric and if the set generalizes to the unit square. Does anybody have an example of a self-similar and symmetric set or, if one does not exist, a reference/proof?

Comment: I think this is ruled out by [Lévy's zero–one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems#L%C3%A9vy's_zero%E2%80%93one_law) .  In the notation of the wikipedia article, $X$ is the indicator function of your self-similar set, and $F_k$ is the field generated by all the dyadic $2^{-k}\times2^{-k}$ subsquares, and $F_\infty$ is the Borel field on the square. Your self-similarity guarantees that all the conditional expectations are the measure of your self-similar set; the conclusion is that $X$ is a constant function.

Comment: Thanks! This pretty much entirely entirely answers my question.